BigQuery SELECT last day of every month on PARTITIONED column
I have the following data in BigQuery.
+---------+---------+------------+
| keyword | qcCount | updateDate |
+---------+---------+------------+

I want to SELECT data FROM my table WHERE updateDate is in the last day of each month, within the specified period.
My purpose is to lower query cost by not filtering all days in the period, but only the last day of each month.
For example, if the period is between 2024-01-01 and 2024-04-01, then only 2024-01-31, 2024-02-29, 2024-03-31 are filtered.
The DATE column, updateDate is daily partitioned, so I should use constant filter only.
But, I cannot come up with the way except dynamic filtering.
Below is my SQL statement. Of course, it didn't work.
SELECT keyword, 
     qcCount, 
     updateDate
FROM my_table
WHERE updateDate IN 
(
   SELECT LAST_DAY(dt) 
   FROM UNNEST(
          GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(2024,1,1), 
          DATE(2024,4,1)
        )
   ) AS dt
);


I created another table with only the last day of each month. But, if any ideas, please tell me.

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE updateDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2024-05-30'  
AND DAY(updateDate) = DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, updateDate) + 1, 0))) 

-- Constant Filter: Only include partitions within the specified period
-- Dynamic Filter: Include only rows where updateDate is the last day of the month
-- This is working in SQL SERVER

Thanks for your opinion. The SQL statement is not compatible with BigQuery, and I think that using data itself as filter, such as DAY(updateDate), is considered a dynamic filter. However, I guess that, by extracting only the date column first and processing it, could reduce the query cost slightly, although not as much as expected. Thank you.
